# Mocking HttpResponseHeaders and cookies in WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my web api controller, and I need to test that a cookie is being retrieved correctly so I want to setup a mock that returns the cookies I want to test for. Cookies are retrieved like so in WebAPI:

```
Request.Headers.GetCookies("CookieName").FirstOrDefault()
```

The request object is mockable but unfortunately I cannot mock the headers property (which is a `HttpRequestHeaders` object) as `HttpRequestHeaders` is sealed and none of its methods are virtual, and it also doesn't implement an interface (good job MS).

Is there any way to mock the getting / setting of cookies in WebAPI or not?

p.s. I don't want to hear that I should not be using cookies in WebAPI, that's what is being done and to change it is outside the scope of my current work

Answer (score 5):

This is what i ended up doing.

To set the Request cookies.

```
  var target = new YourController()
  target.Request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "YourCookieKey=Value;");
```

To read the Response cookie.

```
 var response = target.YourControllerMethod();
 var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourModel>().Result;
 Assert.IsTrue(response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").ToList()[0].Contains("YourCookieKey"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mock the `HttpRequestBase`, a google search and found this -

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
request.SetupGet(r => r.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
request.Object.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("TestCookie", "TestValue"));
request.Object.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("AnotherCookie"));
```

p.s : you should not be using cookies when using web api.